# Remove some quotes for str_word_count

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this function : http://www.seoreviewtools.com/multi-keyword-density-checker-php-script/ but I had some problems to make it work with weird french words. (see my modified version here : http://pastebin.com/m6PjsizX)

As you know `str_word_count()` doesn't work with UTF-8 characters and one may use a third arg to "ignore" those. However, I didn't find a way to make it work with quotes (very common in french).

There three cases of simple quotes in french words :

1. One letter_quote_word (ex. : j'aime, d'habitude, l'avion, s'intégrer)
2. A quote in a word (ex : Aujourd'hui, prud'homme, quelqu'un)
3. Mostly in Brand names, a quote at the end of the word (ex. Super', Vendu')

I'd like to remove some of the quotes in order to process `str_word_count()` without error (maybe with a regular expression and `preg_replace()`) in order to get this result :

```
$str = "J'aime la plage d'aujourd'hui, quelqu'un aimerait-il aller chez Super' pour voir l'avion bleue ?");
MagicFunction($str);
$str = str_word_count($str);
echo $str;
```

> aime la plage aujourd'hui, quelqu'un aimerait-il aller chez Super' pour voir avion bleu

Furthermore there are many quotes (', `, ‘, ’, etc.) and I would like this to work with all types of quotes.

Do you have a solution to make it work this way ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want to remove the apostrophes when they separate two words (`j'aime`, `l'huile`) only and keep them if they are part of one word (`aujourd'hui`, `quelqu'un`, `Super'`)? I see you also want to remove the `j` in `j'aime`, right? Try `'~\b\p{L}[\'\`‘’]~u'` regex with `preg_replace`.

Comment: Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yD8bU8/2) - it just matches an apostrophe after the first letter in a word.

Comment: Indeed it works very well on the demo, thanks. However, I don't why at this point the function actually breaks it and returns '�' when I process "aujourd'hui" for ex. Here is the new source : http://pastebin.com/kFVWHapr

Comment: This is actually quite hard, cause French uses a lot of "contractions". 
Should these be counted as seperate words, or not? That's the question.

I'm sure putting all these characters with accents égu's, accents graves etcetera will mess up PHP echoed output so I always convert them to htmlentities so it can be echoed in the right way.  
eg: 

`$str = "J'aime la plage d'aujourd'hui, quelqu'un aimerait-il aller chez Super' pour voir";`

`$str = htmlentities(html_entity_decode(utf8_encode($str),ENT_QUOTES),ENT_QUOTES);`

`echo str_word_count($str);` 


PHP Says there are 15 words...

Comment: How many words are in that string anyway? :-) See the problem, I'm not sure if PHP is either close or correct.

Comment: @Cyc: You are working with Unicode strings, so *each call* to `preg_replace` must be done with `/u` modifier.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I used them to fix the function and it appears to work, more or less :)

Comment: The regex must be `\b\p{L}['\`‘’]\b` to account for cases like `L'` (the word is a one-letter word with an apostrophe at the end).

Comment: Try `preg_split("/[^\pL\pN']+/u", $str)` instead of `str_word_count`, [see demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/517521).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to

- remove the apostrophes when they separate two words (`j'aime`, `l'huile`) with the first letter that stands for a shortened word
- keep apostrophes that are *inside* a word, excluding the 2nd and last positions in it (like `aujourd'hui`, `quelqu'un`, `Super'`).

I suggest an approach to **remove each 1 single letter at the beginning of a word that is followed with an apostrophe**. All other cases are when a `'` is supposed to be *inside* the word and thus must be kept intact.

```
'~\b\p{L}[\'`‘’]\b~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU3zI5/1)

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/IXVfdh):

```
$re = '~\b\p{L}[\'`‘’]\b~u'; 
$str = "J'aime la plage d'aujourd'hui, quelqu‘un aimerait-il aller chez Super’ pour voir l`avion bleue ? l'école L'"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
echo $result;
// => aime la plage aujourd'hui, quelqu‘un aimerait-il aller chez Super’ pour voir avion bleue ? école L'
```

**NOTE** that you must use `/u` modifier with each call to *preg_replace* when working with Unicode strings.

Comment: Please check if the answer is working for you. If not, please specify where this fails.